# Is it possible to delay a device plugged into a USB port on a rpi4 from getting power for about 10-15 seconds?

Tags: delay

RPI4 running on an arcade cabinet using ArPiCade software. What happens is this particular USB device automatically assigns itself to joystick1 once booted up which then throws off the softwares internal assigned joysticks by 1. IE joy 2 becomes 3 etc. If I wait until system boots and then plug in my USB device everything works as it should. My device gets detected as joy4. The first 3 joys are on the gpio pins, 1 being virtual. They must stay in that order for everything to work correctly. Currently I have a USB cable with an on/off switch as a dirty workaround. I've tested waiting 10 seconds before flipping switch to on and it maintains the order of everything. Id just like it completely hands free.

I haven't tried anything as my Linux skills are lacking. I've been told what I want to do is possible but I've never found a solution